# I'm trying to improve my HTML5 Component/Entity/Systems engine, to get as close as possible to the paradigm. What can be improved?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, game-engine

After different paradigms used to create HTML5 game engines, I'm very curious about the Component/Entity/Systems paradigm ; after a friend which is very skillful, told me about it.

If you don't know about it, it's rather simple:

**An empty object called an entity**

```
function GameEntity(){
            this.components = {};
            this.createComponent = function(name, args) {
                this.components[name] = new componentList[name](this, args);
            }
        }
```

**Contains elements which are modular in their nature and as independant as possible**

```
'position': function(parentEntity){
    this.entity = parentEntity;

    var x = 50;
    var y = 50;

    this.setPosition = function(newX, newY) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }
    this.getPosition = function() {
        return {"x" : x, "y" : y};
    }
    this.setX = function(value) {
        x = value;
    }
    this.setY = function(value) {
        y = value;
    }
    this.getX = function() {
        return x;
    }
    this.getY = function() {
        return y;
    }
                },
```

**Which are acted upon by systems, each proper to a component**

```
 for (var i =0 ; i<game.ent.entityCounter ; i++){
    game.ent.entities[i].components['mouvement'].update();
    game.ent.entities[i].components['graphics'].update(); 
}
```

I've been trying to follow Unity's logic, so far.
Even though it's not a very precise question, how can I improve this little engine?

http://jsfiddle.net/5etgx/2/

It's very basic, but that's mostly the structure that focuses my attention, rather than the functionnality.

Let me know if you think anything is not done in a good manner.

Comment: Good question, but it's more a question for SO's sister code review site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't know. I'll go there, then.